# How is this pure-CSS drawer in a static-height iframe affecting the scroll position of its parent frame?

Tags: css, iframe, vertical-scrolling

**Background**

I'm trying to implement this [pure-css drawer](http://mac81.github.io/pure-drawer/) within an iframe.  The iframe has content above it (in the parent frame), so it's not at the top of the page.

---

**What I've been able to find so far**

- There's no JavaScript being called to attempt to set the scroll height.
- The author is using a hidden checkbox and its different states (active, checked, unchecked) to style the drawer with animation in an open or closed state.

---

**Question**

- How is CSS within a static height iframe affecting the scroll height of the parent?
  (My goal is to remove the unexpected scrolling jumpiness as seen in the gif and snippet below)

---

**Snippet and animated .gif of the scrolling being reset to the top:**

```html
<div style="height : 200px; background : whitesmoke;">
  Here is a top div with some height
</div>
<iframe width="100%" height="500px" src="https://mac81.github.io/pure-drawer/" style="overflow : hidden;"><iframe>
```

[image: Animated gif of scrolling issue]

[edit] 
— after posting my question it looks like the snippet is affecting the scroll position of the StackOverflow page (top frame I'm presuming).
- this is on Chrome 59.0.3071.115 on Mac OsX Sierra

Comment: That's crazy, any chance you could replicate this using just a checkbox and some css? Trying to reproduce it might even lead you to the answer. Does seem really weird though.